# Unorthodox data-model extensions

Tags: ios, core-data, database-migration, key-value-store

**Background Details**

I've got a production iOS app that uses a relatively complex data-model, managed by Core Data.  I'd like to make a number of modifications and extensions to it, and none of the planned modifications would be adding or modifying relationships between entities.  Nor would they involve large amounts of new data, nor information that must be super-quickly accessible from a performance point of view.  It's also information that is read-only on the client-side of things.

From past experience I've generally discovered that updating a data-model in Core Data using the [officially sanctioned approach](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH4-SW1) is unreliable, time-consuming, difficult to test, and nowhere near as "lightweight" as the documentation would have me believe.

**The Question**

Is there a good alternative to extending the data-model the Core Data way that will yield a reasonable result with no (or few) hidden gotchas?

For instance, it seems at least theoretically possible to use `NSUserDefaults`, the Keychain, or just an arbitrary file that I create in the filesystem as a key-value store, implement a simple key-generation protocol like `<object-id>_fieldName` or `<object-id>_extendedFields`, store the extra data off to the side, and then implement corresponding accessors on my Core Data entities so that the difference in terms of storage location is transparent to the rest of the application.  That seems roughly analogous to applications that use a traditional RDBMS for some things, and then a NoSQL storage layer for things that are sort of 'tangentially attached' to the relational entities but not directly relevant in the relational context.

Would something like that be a reasonable (if unconventional) approach?  Are there any serious hidden pitfalls that come to mind, or any alternative approach that seems better (short of doing an actual Core Data migration)?